# MKTileOverlay from local tiles lags when zooming

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have tiles stored locally on device and I'm loading them with the following code

```
override func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL {
    let tilePath = Bundle.main.url(
        forResource: "\(path.y)",
        withExtension: "png",
        subdirectory: "tiles/\(path.z)/\(path.x)",
        localization: nil)
    
    if let tile = tilePath {
        return tile
    } else {
        return Bundle.main.url(
            forResource: "empty",
            withExtension: "png",
            subdirectory: "tiles",
            localization: nil)!
    }
}
```

I create a `MKTileOverlayRenderer` in my viewModel

```
let overlay = TileOverlay()
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
    overlay.minimumZ = 13
    overlay.maximumZ = 16
    tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)
```

And add that overlay in `viewDidLoad` of my ViewController to the mapView

```
mapView.addOverlay(viewModel.tileRenderer.overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
```

This calls my delegate method `rendererFor overlay:`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    return viewModel.tileRenderer
}
```

I only have a small sample of tiles, 17MB, however there is a lag when zooming in and out and even sometimes on initial load of the overlay. I've even restricted the mapView boundary with `MKMapView.CameraBoundary` and zoom with `MKMapView.CameraZoomRange`.

**How can I prevent this lag?**

I'm using a Simulator: `iPhone11`, `iOS 13.5`